# Use special agent for whole pipeline when a condition is met

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

There is declarative pipeline. In the beginning of pipeline block the agent selection is made using `agent` directive. Label-based selection is being conducted. Agent selected this way is the standard/default agent.

How to set for whole pipeline a special agent when certain condition is met?

The plan is to do condition check based on pipeline's one parameter >> can that work?

What are the points the chosen approach needs to address?

Current solution blueprint:

- Groovy code prior to pipeline block
- Mentioned groovy code sets a variable based on value of pipeline's parameter *how to access pipeline's parameter from within Groovy code located out of pipeline?*
- `agent` section uses variable set in Groovy code matching label special agent got attached to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Jenkins.io and Cloudbees do not support dynamic agent selection with Declarative Pipeline syntax. Hence adding "when" expression within agent block will not work. However, the below approach can be tried
1. Create pipeline library - with a groovy file in vars folder. Keep all the stages inside this file and parameterize the "Agent" block
2. Jenkinsfile - embed the library inside Jenkinsfile and invoke the above groovy file using call(body) syntax. Pass agent deciding parameter from this Jenkinsfile.

For library syntax, please refer this url
[Shared Library syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)