# How can I conditionally create an agent "object" for pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a pipeline where I want to conditionally use to different *types* of agents.

I don't want to set a default at the pipeline level because then that agent type will be provisioned every time even if it isn't going to be used

I have k8s slaves and ECS slave, I basically want to do this, but this doesn't work:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        if (true) {
            kubernetes {
                defaultContainer "mycontainer"
                yaml 'my podspec'
            }
        } else {
            node {
                label 'my-ecs-cluster'
                customWorkspace 'myworkspace'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hope this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225553/use-special-agent-for-whole-pipeline-when-a-condition-is-met

Answer (score 0):

Hope below sample pipeline script might help you to solve your issue.

```
pipeline
{
    agent none
    parameters
    {
        choice(name: 'agent', choices: ['master','slave'], description: 'Agent Selection!')
    }
    stages
    {
        stage('Say Hello - Master')
        {
            when
            {
                expression
                {
                    agent == 'master' 
                }
            }
            agent
            {
                node
                {
                    label 'master'
                }
            }
            steps
            {
                echo 'hello master'
            }
        }
         stage('Say Hello - Slave')
        {
            when
            {
                expression
                {
                    agent == 'slave' 
                }
            }
            agent
            {
                node
                {
                    label 'slave'
                }
            }
            steps
            {
                echo 'hello slave'
            }
        }
    }
}
```